# Is there a way to list collections with mongoskin?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I already have an established database connection. I need to list the names of the collections in the database. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To show collections into database from mongo shell :

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

So to show collection in mongoskin try that

```
var collections = db.collections();
collections.each(function(err, collection) {
    console.log(collection);
});
```

according to this link [Mongoskin Tutorial](http://www.hacksparrow.com/mongoskin-tutorial-with-examples.html)

Comment: `db` doesn't have a method called `getCollectionNames()`. Try it and your server gets an internal error.

Comment: according to db.js https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/db.js#L17

Comment: Just please update the first row in your answer as well.

Comment: @PerakR The first line is how you look in the mongo shell. The second section is the code for mongoskin use

Comment: the code for mongoskin doesn't work. any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collectionNames(function(err, collectionArrayResult) {
    //Now do something with collectionArrayResult
});
```

The result is an array of objects with a 'name' property, like this:

```
[
   { name: '<dbName>.<collectionName>' },
   ...
]
```

Careful though -  `<dbName>.system.indexes` will be returned too.

Comment: This is the correct answer without using extra packages. If using Meteor by any chance you can get the `db` object from `var db = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo.db;`