# How to get a list of all collections with mongoskin

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

The goal is to get a list of all the collections in the database using mongoskin.

I know you can enter the db.getCollectionNames() method in mongo shell to do this, but I haven't found a way to achieve the same in my app.

I have already looked at a similar post on SO ([Is there a way to list collections with mongoskin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565191/is-there-a-way-to-list-collections-with-mongoskin)) and tried the posted solution without success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's collectionNames().  It returns databasename.collectionname (ex. "test.user") though... but you can do some string manipulations to get rid of that if you need.

```
db.collectionNames(function(err, items) {
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.name);
  });
});
```

Comment: my hero. just wondering, is db.collectionNames a default mongo method or a mongoskin specific one?

Comment: it's from mongo-native driver http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collectionnames.  Mongoskin is based on mongo-native so if you can't find what you need in mongoskin doc [not surprised :)], look in mongo-native doc.